# Is there a way to access MySQL and/or PHP pages from Lotus Notes?

Tags: php, mysql, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a full internet application served on a LAMP server, which I have complete access (root) to all of the server settings and web page files.  Unfortunately, due to policy, it cannot be accessed outside of the company location.

However, we are using Lotus Notes for an email/database system, which is fully accessible from anywhere with an internet connection.  All users have the Notes client installed, and the interaction can be one way (MySQL --> Domino Server).  There are no concerns about access or security through Lotus Notes from management.

Is there a way to have notes access my LAMP server, and either serve up webpages and files, or develop a quick interface to access the MySQL database?

I am assuming that the Domino Server can access MySQL through ODBC, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or direction!

Comment: If policy is that it shouldn't be accessed outside the company location, why are you trying to allow access outside the company location against policy instead of pushing for a change in the policy?

Comment: @David, policy clearly allows access for any lotus notes application.  They are concerned about security and somehow believe that LN is more secure than a webserver (https not withstanding).  Lack of understand is the root cause, but if they give an opportunity for a work around, I would like to investigate it.

Comment: It might be helpful to add something about that in the question, so that people reading know you're doing it because management would likely allow access via the Notes client. The way it's written now, it sounds like they don't want users to access the data, not just that they're concerned about the security.

Comment: @David, I see your point.  I added some information to clarify this in the original post.

Comment: There are many possible solutions for you.  What versions of Notes and Domino are you running? Also, do you need real-time access to the MySQL data, or is it sufficient to use a synchronization solution that moves data from MySQL to Domoino on a nightly basis.

Comment: @rhsatrhs, we are using a Domino server version 8.5, and various client side levels (7.0.2 to 8.5).  Any solution (including batch updates) would work, although real time would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have old Notes clients, IBM's latest XPages technology is out of the question -- unless your Domino server is already open for HTTP, in which case you can use XPages on Domino to get information from MySQL and serve it to a browser.  This would be the most up-to-date technical direction to go in.

But in general, the answer is yes, there are several ways for Domino servers to access MySQL data, and if you don't need to be using all the latest toys there are some old standby tools to get the job done.  There is an IBM solution called Domino Enterprise Connection Services, or DECS, that performs real-time mapping between Notes databases and relational databases.  You can find information about it [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/decs/).  Another IBM solution called Lotus Enterprise Integrator, or LEI, is designed for batch transfer operations between Notes databases and relational databases.  You can find information about it [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/lei/).  You can also use the @DbLookup function in Lotus formula language or LCLSX (LotusScript Connector Extensions) in LotusScript code for events or agents in a Notes database.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I will check this information out, it seems pretty extensive.

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of choices and a lot of detail.  In reality, StackOverflow is more useful for more specific questions rather than general ones like this one.  But now you should have plenty of info to help get you started... So you can then come back and ask the more specific questions! :-)